# DateTime Parse missing on iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a DatePicker to a Xamarin Forms project. I have lifted a sample from [Xamarins website](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker/) or also explained below:

```
<DatePicker VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
    <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
    <DatePicker.MinimumDate>
        <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
            <x:Arguments>
                <x:String>Jan 1 2000</x:String>
            </x:Arguments>
        </sys:DateTime>
    </DatePicker.MinimumDate>
    <DatePicker.MaximumDate>
        <sys:DateTime x:FactoryMethod="Parse">
            <x:Arguments>
                <x:String>Dec 31 2050</x:String>
            </x:Arguments>
        </sys:DateTime>
    </DatePicker.MaximumDate>
</DatePicker>
```

I also have both namespaces included:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

When running this on the iPhone Simulator (version 11.2) it happily renders and works however if I run it on a physical device (version 11.2) it throws the following exception:

> System.MissingMemberException
>
> No static method found for System.DateTime::Parse (System.String)

Has anyone encountered this issue or know of a reason why this would be failing?

Comment: I'd guess that the linker is stripping it out - see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Comment: @Jason thanks for the link. To quote from that link: "For performance reasons this is the default setting when your IDE targets for the iOS simulator. For devices builds this should only be used as a workaround whenever the linker contains a bug that prevents your application to run." That seems like a strange decision to make the Simulator not really mimic a device... I shall test out no linking and see how it goes

Comment: there are a lot of ways the simulator does not mimic the device - that's why it's not technically an emulator

Comment: @Bijington Not a bug ;-) Enable the XAML compiler for that page and/or create linker file to preserve it, and/or reference `Parse` in code so the linker sees it being used. Also you will need the linker enabled to produce an `.ipa` that is valid for App Store submission.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks, to prove your point calling DateTime.Parse resolves my issue. I didn't expect the compiler to be so helpful to strip out things it doesn't think I am using :)

Comment: @Bijington The Mono linker  does an *static* evaluation, thus non-compiled XAML is not reviewed since it would be serialized/reflection-based at runtime. Without the linker, apps would be huge and in terms of iOS Apps, those apps have to have `Xamarin.iOS.dll` linked to remove the features you are not using otherwise App submission would fail due to the entire iOS API being referenced without *all* the iOS entitlements enabled...

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the explanation it does all make sense. I just found it a little confusing that the simulator environment wouldn't show the same behaviour the a device would but I can accept it now :). I'll happily accept an answer if you wanted to post one covering your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify on the answer as mentioned by @Jason and @SushHangover.

The Mono linker does a static evaluation, thus non-compiled XAML is not reviewed since it would be serialised/reflection-based at runtime. Without the linker, apps would be huge and in terms of iOS Apps, those apps have to have Xamarin.iOS.dll linked to remove the features you are not using otherwise App submission would fail due to the entire iOS API being referenced without all the iOS entitlements enabled. Also explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/).

In short the quick fix was to refer to `DateTime.Parse` in code in order to prove the point. I shall look in to actually forcing it in the compiler when I get a chance as I don't need to call `DateTime.Parse` in code.